# adding html tags to selected text in textarea. Why does "if('selectionStart' in textarea)" need to be in there?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, selection, selection-api

I found javascript code that allows me to add html tags around text that I have highlighted in the `textarea` field:

```
    <textarea id="myArea" cols="30" spellcheck="false">Select some text within this field.</textarea>
        <button onclick="ModifySelection ()">Modify the current selection</button>

<script>
      function ModifySelection () {
                var textarea = document.getElementById("myArea");
          if('selectionStart' in textarea){
          if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) {
                        var newText = textarea.value.substring (0, textarea.selectionStart) + 
                            "[start]" + textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + "[end]" +
                            textarea.value.substring (textarea.selectionEnd);
                        textarea.value = newText;
                    }
                }
    }
</script>
```

My questions pertain to this line, `if('selectionStart' in textarea){`:

1. What does the line mean exactly?
2. Why does `selectionStart` have to be in quotes?
3. `selectionStart` is usually appended to an object like
       `"textarea"(textarea.selectionStart)`, how is it possible to refer
   to
       it by itself?
4. Is `If(X in Y){}` standard javascript syntax or does it work
       specifically for`selectionStart`?

note: I'm testing this in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `if('selectionStart' in textarea)` is feature testing - it checks whether the `textarea` object has a `selectionStart` property.
2. It needs to be in quotes as otherwise it would be interpreted as a variable (which may or may not exist in the current context).
3. It depends on the browser and what version of HTML is supported and rendered.
4. Yes it is normal javascript syntax. It is used to test if the specified property is in the object. See [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in) on MDN.

Comment: if it is in quotes, wouldn't 'selectionStart' be interpreted as a string and not a property of an object?

Comment: @user701510 - That's what it is supposed to do. It looks up the property by _name_.